# ng build --prod doesn't generate dist folder (angular 7)

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-cli, angular7

- Running **ng build** generates dist folder
- Running **ng build --prod** succeeds but does not generate

Have reloaded VS code, refreshed, checked angular cli, to no avail.
[image]
[image]

Fragment of **angular.json** which could be of usage:

```
  "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
```

Comment: run `ng build --verbose --prod` but I've never seen this happen without an error.

Comment: yea, that did it, but I don't like forcing the output, do you have any idea why --prod didn't write. Running macos mojave as OS

Comment: You could elaborate a little bit more on it if you wish and I'll accept your answer, saved my time...

Comment: I did nothing... I think you've made a small mistake and thought `dist` wasn't created. The `--verbose` just toggles more console logging. Most likely VS code wasn't updating it's UI to show that the folder had been created. This happens to me with WebStorm all the time, and I have to force the file explorer to update. If the problem is solved, then I would recommend deleting the question.